# How to use jquery accessible-mega-menu in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have integrated Jquery Accessible mega menu in Angular and created a directive to apply. But this works partially. When I tab to parent menu item this will open the child menu but I couldn't close this again unless to tab next item. But the plug-in support open and close through space bar. Additionally, menu item click is not supporting.

Is anything wrong?

**Angular**

```
angular
        .module('app.core')
        .directive('accessibleMegaMenu', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.accessibleMegaMenu(scope.$eval(attrs.accessibleMegaMenu));

                }
            }
        }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div accessible-mega-menu="{
            uuidPrefix: 'accessible-megamenu',
            menuClass: 'nav-menu',
            topNavItemClass: 'nav-item',
            panelClass: 'sub-nav',
            panelGroupClass: 'sub-menu',
            hoverClass: 'hover',
            focusClass: 'focus',
            openClass: 'open'
        }">


        <ul class="page-sidebar-menu page-sidebar-menu-closed nav-menu">
                <!-- DOC: To remove the search box from the sidebar you just need to completely remove the below "sidebar-search-wrapper" LI element -->

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/" ui-sref="dashboard" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkHome" class="active" ng-click="vm.menuActive()">
                        <i class="icon-home"></i>
                        <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="javascript:;" ui-sref="policysearch" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkPolicy" ng-click="vm.menuActive()">
                        <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
                        <span class="title">Search</span>
                        <span class="arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" >
                    <a href="#/todo" ui-sref="tasksearch" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="sub-nav" aria-controls="sub-nav">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i>
                        <span class="title">Contact</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" aria-labelledby="dbdLnkTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" id="sub-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="task in vm.availableTasks">
                            <a id="dbdLnkAvailable{{$index}}" href="javascript:;" ng-click="vm.handleTask(task)" ng-class="{'cn-active' : vm.activeMenuItem}">
                                <i ng-class="task.icon"></i> <span class="title">{{task.description}}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Where you use `accessibleMegaMenu` directive?

Comment: updated. It was missed